# Image not showing in html using laravel asset

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a problem displaying the image using asset in laravel by passing it to js variable, Is there any other way to do this?

```
var baseurl = "{!! asset('images/favicon.png') !!}";

var header = '<table border="1" align="right" style="text-align:center" width="100%">'+
    '<tr>'+
        '<td rowspan="4"><img width="50" height="50" src="'+baseurl+'"></td>' +
    +'</tr>'+
</table>'
```

Comment: Hi, show your path image, please...

Comment: My path image is in laravel public/images/

Comment: Keep it simple, use `src="/images/favicon.png"`. If your site isn't in subdirectory that's enough.

Comment: make sure your image is exist on public/images/

Comment: The image is present in my public directory

Comment: Maybe theres something wrong in passing my asset in a js variable

Comment: I tried doing it simple but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

javascript its a client-side language and laravel executes first in the server side.

The client will not be able to read `{!! asset('images/favicon.png') !!}`, as this is a request that its made in the server render.

When you put that in the page with javascript, the server is already done generating the page and will not proceed to execute that (or any other) function call.

To solve that you will have to call the absolute path of the image without the asset() (point directly to the domain, as @Daniel suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of: `var baseurl = "{!! asset('images/favicon.png') !!}";`

Try using

```
var baseurl = "{{ asset('images/favicon.png') }}";
```